# appcompat v7 overflow icon color different in V-21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, overflow-menu

I have `Imagebutton` with `src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"` using appcompat-v7 21.0.3.

```
<ImageButton
  android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_height_material"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_height_material"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha" />
```

It's showing me **black** overflow button until api 20. In **api >=21 It shows white** icon which is not visible correctly in my layout.

See Images.

**In kitkat** 
[image]

**In Lollipop**
[image]

As seen, It's white in >=21 .

I have single styles.xml file for all versions as follows.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>

    </style>
```

So , what should be hack here , any help would be great.

```
Note : -I am using this button in recyclerview item layout. 

       -Appcompat v7-22.2.0 produces the same result.
```

Comment: I think it's using your Accent color. Try overriding the color in values-v21

Comment: Or if that doesn't work, manually tint the icon (programmatically)

Comment: thnx for suggession , overriding accent color not working. An manually tinting may overhelm the system , what you say , as it's in recyclerview item layout.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong when setting the `android:tint` property. [See the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:tint)

Comment: android:tint works great. thank you. @reVerse .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @reVerse ,

`android:tint` works great which tints the image with specified color.